# How to fetch data from an API in Java based Android app

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am trying to fetch data from Jamendo API by using the track endpoint link to get only yoga music and then display it to an another activity.

- I've made a MusicListScreen which has adapter that displays the data fetched from the api.
- YogaTracks class has the attributes of the json response I should get.
- the json response:

```
{
  "headers":{
    "status":"success",
    "code":0,
    "error_message":"",
    "warnings":"",
    "results_count":2
  },
  "results":[
    {
      "id":"1532771",
      "name":"Let Me Hear You I",
      "duration":54,
      "artist_id":"461414",
      "artist_name":"Paul Werner",
      "artist_idstr":"PaulWernerMusic",
      "album_name":"Let Me Hear You I",
      "album_id":"404140",
      "license_ccurl":"http:\/\/creativecommons.org\/licenses\/by-nc-nd\/3.0\/",
      "position":1,
      "releasedate":"2018-03-15",
      "album_image":"https:\/\/usercontent.jamendo.com?type=album&id=404140&width=300&trackid=1532771",
      "audio":"https:\/\/prod-1.storage.jamendo.com\/?trackid=1532771&format=mp31&from=app-devsite",
      "audiodownload":"https:\/\/prod-1.storage.jamendo.com\/download\/track\/1532771\/mp32\/",
      "prourl":"https:\/\/licensing.jamendo.com\/track\/1532771",
      "shorturl":"https:\/\/jamen.do\/t\/1532771",
      "shareurl":"https:\/\/www.jamendo.com\/track\/1532771",
      "waveform":"{
        \"peaks\":[
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          10,
          12,
          7,
          7,
          1,
          5,
          1,
          7,
          2,
          10,
          13,
          9,
          8,
          1,
          3,
          1,
          4,
          6,
          3,
          14,
          9,
          7,
          7,
          6,
          4,
          5,
          16,
          11,
          16,
          4,
          4,
          2,
          2,
          8,
          7,
          10,
          11,
          17,
          18,
          11,
          6,
          5,
          2,
          0,
          11,
          9,
          14,
          8,
          2,
          3,
          1,
          14,
          12,
          9,
          1,
          1,
          2,
          0,
          3,
          0,
          11,
          10,
          10,
          12,
          14,
          24,
          49,
          24,
          11,
          8,
          8,
          17,
          17,
          9,
          20,
          21,
          17,
          16,
          11,
          9,
          9,
          15,
          12,
          18,
          7,
          2,
          4,
          1,
          22,
          19,
          14,
          5,
          5,
          2,
          0,
          6,
          0,
          14,
          10,
          10,
          13,
          15,
          16,
          9,
          13,
          12,
          5,
          9,
          10,
          10,
          6,
          23,
          18,
          13,
          12,
          15,
          3,
          1,
          20,
          12,
          22,
          6,
          7,
          2,
          3,
          14,
          11,
          9,
          1,
          13,
          10,
          7,
          6,
          23,
          47,
          33,
          29,
          23,
          20,
          14,
          7,
          5,
          7,
          10,
          5,
          2,
          0,
          19,
          74,
          70,
          41,
          17,
          27,
          30,
          30,
          24,
          22,
          75,
          69,
          54,
          20,
          18,
          26,
          29,
          26,
          28,
          49,
          70,
          61,
          34,
          16,
          27,
          32,
          33,
          25,
          50,
          70,
          70,
          32,
          15,
          28,
          27,
          29,
          25,
          45,
          88,
          64,
          33,
          15,
          29,
          30,
          30,
          24,
          30,
          69,
          74,
          49,
          23,
          31,
          38,
          39,
          34,
          29,
          80,
          81,
          55,
          22,
          22,
          28,
          28,
          30,
          27,
          62,
          73,
          60,
          28,
          16,
          28,
          28,
          30,
          22,
          56,
          72,
          65,
          37,
          14,
          33,
          30,
          27,
          21,
          37,
          71,
          65,
          39,
          13,
          28,
          31,
          28,
          25,
          24,
          67,
          79,
          54,
          23,
          18,
          26,
          27,
          24,
          19,
          60,
          69,
          55,
          24,
          19,
          27,
          29,
          29,
          21,
          65,
          75,
          59,
          24,
          20,
          33,
          28,
          26,
          23,
          40,
          74,
          64,
          32,
          14,
          62,
          29,
          27,
          19,
          27,
          83,
          78,
          43,
          13,
          29,
          30,
          27,
          24,
          27,
          74,
          69,
          56,
          14,
          17,
          29,
          29,
          25,
          25,
          64,
          26,
          19,
          17,
          12,
          12,
          10,
          8,
          7,
          55,
          74,
          62,
          25,
          17,
          30,
          30,
          26,
          21,
          34,
          69,
          73,
          47,
          18,
          21,
          29,
          26,
          26,
          31,
          71,
          77,
          50,
          16,
          25,
          27,
          28,
          28,
          23,
          88,
          74,
          48,
          10,
          21,
          27,
          32,
          23,
          19,
          64,
          87,
          66,
          38,
          19,
          24,
          31,
          26,
          21,
          59,
          84,
          73,
          32,
          17,
          26,
          27,
          28,
          26,
          50,
          84,
          68,
          41,
          15,
          24,
          29,
          28,
          21,
          26,
          76,
          71,
          56,
          14,
          22,
          29,
          26,
          23,
          18,
          76,
          74,
          59,
          20,
          14,
          27,
          26,
          23,
          20,
          45,
          77,
          60,
          32,
          16,
          26,
          29,
          26,
          25,
          48,
          73,
          67,
          31,
          19,
          29,
          30,
          27,
          25,
          35,
          100,
          66,
          39,
          11,
          23,
          25,
          26,
          22,
          20,
          79,
          79,
          47,
          17,
          23,
          34,
          34,
          27,
          23,
          72,
          82,
          58,
          22,
          19,
          27,
          28,
          27,
          30,
          59,
          55,
          60,
          32,
          23,
          27,
          28,
          24,
          20,
          52,
          68,
          72,
          52,
          22,
          16,
          23,
          23,
          21,
          32,
          73,
          30,
          30,
          42,
          35,
          28,
          20,
          20,
          22,
          70,
          58,
          17,
          28,
          37,
          35,
          27,
          24,
          22,
          66,
          62,
          21,
          31,
          38,
          35,
          29,
          26,
          24,
          63,
          68,
          24,
          29,
          36,
          40,
          32,
          24,
          20,
          45,
          88,
          51,
          24,
          22,
          30,
          34,
          29,
          20,
          27,
          98,
          68,
          49,
          15,
          21,
          27,
          27,
          27,
          29,
          80,
          78,
          55,
          24,
          19,
          28,
          29,
          23,
          19,
          72,
          73,
          76,
          31,
          35,
          88,
          79,
          66,
          35,
          47,
          66,
          59,
          25,
          42,
          75,
          77,
          69,
          52,
          36,
          62,
          68,
          52,
          25,
          50,
          68,
          61,
          44,
          32,
          66,
          68,
          64,
          46,
          42,
          84,
          71,
          64,
          36,
          63,
          63,
          62,
          34,
          39,
          75,
          58,
          67,
          69,
          62,
          35,
          34,
          82,
          54,
          42,
          25,
          52,
          77,
          54,
          34,
          32,
          76,
          58,
          58,
          33,
          32,
          32,
          44,
          39,
          21,
          31,
          12,
          33,
          22,
          34,
          24,
          27,
          61,
          57,
          50,
          19,
          24,
          31,
          27,
          25,
          21,
          63,
          69,
          59,
          23,
          15,
          33,
          27,
          26,
          21,
          45,
          66,
          62,
          31,
          20,
          40,
          34,
          33,
          35,
          46,
          62,
          69,
          42,
          18,
          33,
          27,
          26,
          26,
          32,
          75,
          59,
          45,
          22,
          30,
          30,
          28,
          25,
          23,
          66,
          72,
          53,
          27,
          22,
          32,
          29,
          27,
          20,
          62,
          79,
          54,
          20,
          22,
          39,
          33,
          30,
          29,
          56,
          68,
          61,
          36,
          16,
          34,
          31,
          29,
          25,
          46,
          53,
          62,
          42,
          19,
          33,
          28,
          30,
          25,
          32,
          70,
          66,
          48,
          16,
          27,
          30,
          29,
          22,
          19,
          57,
          65,
          57,
          38,
          30,
          37,
          29,
          30,
          27,
          55,
          72,
          62,
          29,
          22,
          34,
          27,
          27,
          24,
          51,
          78,
          61,
          32,
          17,
          33,
          29,
          28,
          23,
          34,
          65,
          68,
          45,
          14,
          59,
          35,
          30,
          29,
          27,
          72,
          72,
          45,
          17,
          34,
          33,
          29,
          28,
          30,
          62,
          62,
          56,
          30,
          22,
          36,
          32,
          26,
          27,
          58,
          50,
          53,
          28,
          15,
          35,
          30,
          26,
          21,
          50,
          68,
          63,
          38,
          18,
          30,
          27,
          27,
          23,
          27,
          64,
          70,
          52,
          19,
          27,
          33,
          31,
          32,
          32,
          63,
          73,
          55,
          18,
          24,
          29,
          28,
          31,
          26,
          63,
          71,
          60,
          22,
          19,
          32,
          29,
          28,
          21,
          52,
          70,
          63,
          34,
          17,
          36,
          31,
          30,
          22,
          48,
          75,
          68,
          35,
          22,
          33,
          29,
          26,
          26,
          40,
          67,
          63,
          51,
          20,
          29,
          34,
          30,
          29,
          26,
          61,
          59,
          51,
          19,
          30,
          38,
          32,
          25,
          20,
          61,
          67,
          61,
          28,
          18,
          35,
          29,
          26,
          23,
          41,
          73,
          64,
          38,
          19,
          33,
          30,
          31,
          34,
          44,
          64,
          65,
          40,
          28,
          34,
          29,
          32,
          28,
          25,
          70,
          66,
          42,
          22,
          31,
          31,
          29,
          26,
          22,
          61,
          71,
          51,
          29,
          39,
          47,
          32,
          32,
          31,
          58,
          73,
          66,
          29,
          16,
          39,
          28,
          28,
          25,
          55,
          68,
          56,
          31,
          16,
          29,
          20,
          18,
          18,
          17,
          8,
          3,
          2,
          6,
          3,
          1,
          1,
          1,
          0,
          1,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          10,
          15,
          8,
          13,
          9,
          3,
          2,
          1,
          1,
          4,
          18,
          13,
          14,
          11,
          5,
          2,
          2,
          1,
          43,
          38,
          26,
          23,
          22,
          21,
          20,
          19,
          13,
          12,
          13,
          12,
          10,
          7,
          4,
          1,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }      ",
```

MusicListScrenn class

```
package com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.adapters.AdapterHome;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.adapters.AdapterMusicList;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.databasehelper.DataManager;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.models.ModelBlogCategory;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.models.ModelMainCategory;
import com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.models.ModelMusicCategory;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import JamendoAPI.JamendoApiService;
import JamendoAPI.YogaTracks;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MusicListScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recMainCategory;
    DataManager dataManager;
    ArrayList<YogaTracks> mainCategoryList;
    AdapterMusicList adapterMainCategory;
    TextView tvtitle;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_list_screen);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        mainCategoryList = new ArrayList<YogaTracks>();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.jamendo.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JamendoApiService api = retrofit.create(JamendoApiService.class);

        Call<YogaTracks> call = api.getYogaTracks("db9569db", "jsonpretty", "meditation");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<YogaTracks>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<YogaTracks> call, Response<YogaTracks> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            YogaTracks obj = new YogaTracks();
                            obj.setAlbum_id(jsonObject.getString("album_id"));
                            obj.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            mainCategoryList.add(obj);

                            Log.e("Verify", obj.getAlbum_id() );

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }


                    Log.e("MyApp", "API call successful" );
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<YogaTracks> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("MyApp", "API call failed" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });



        init();
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String tit= intent.getStringExtra("title");
        tvtitle.setText(tit);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapterMainCategory = new AdapterMusicList(mainCategoryList,MusicListScreen.this);
        recMainCategory.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recMainCategory.setAdapter(adapterMainCategory);

    }
    private void init() {
        recMainCategory = findViewById(R.id.recMainCategory);
        tvtitle = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void backClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

API Interface

```
package JamendoAPI;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface JamendoApiService
{
    @GET("https://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/tracks/?client_id=db9569db&format=jsonpretty&tags=yoga")
    Call<YogaTracks>getYogaTracks(@Query("db9569db") String clientId,
                                               @Query("jsonpretty") String format,
                                               @Query("yoga") String tags);

}
```

YogaTracks class

```
package JamendoAPI;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class YogaTracks implements Serializable {

   private List<YogaTracks> musics;

    private String id;

    private String name;

    public List<YogaTracks> getMusics() {
        return musics;
    }

    public void setMusics(List<YogaTracks> musics) {
        this.musics = musics;
    }

    private int duration;

    private String artist_id;

    private String artist_name;

    private String artist_idstr;

    private String album_name;

    private String album_id;
    private String license_ccurl;
    private int position;

    private String releasedate;

    private String album_image;

    private String audio;

    private String audiodownload;

    private String prourl;

    private String shorturl;

    private String shareurl;

    private String waveform;

    private String image;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getArtist_id() {
        return artist_id;
    }

    public void setArtist_id(String artist_id) {
        this.artist_id = artist_id;
    }

    public String getArtist_name() {
        return artist_name;
    }

    public void setArtist_name(String artist_name) {
        this.artist_name = artist_name;
    }

    public String getArtist_idstr() {
        return artist_idstr;
    }

    public void setArtist_idstr(String artist_idstr) {
        this.artist_idstr = artist_idstr;
    }

    public String getAlbum_name() {
        return album_name;
    }

    public void setAlbum_name(String album_name) {
        this.album_name = album_name;
    }

    public String getAlbum_id() {
        return album_id;
    }

    public void setAlbum_id(String album_id) {
        this.album_id = album_id;
    }

    public String getLicense_ccurl() {
        return license_ccurl;
    }

    public void setLicense_ccurl(String license_ccurl) {
        this.license_ccurl = license_ccurl;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getReleasedate() {
        return releasedate;
    }

    public void setReleasedate(String releasedate) {
        this.releasedate = releasedate;
    }

    public String getAlbum_image() {
        return album_image;
    }

    public void setAlbum_image(String album_image) {
        this.album_image = album_image;
    }

    public String getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(String audio) {
        this.audio = audio;
    }

    public String getAudiodownload() {
        return audiodownload;
    }

    public void setAudiodownload(String audiodownload) {
        this.audiodownload = audiodownload;
    }

    public String getProurl() {
        return prourl;
    }

    public void setProurl(String prourl) {
        this.prourl = prourl;
    }

    public String getShorturl() {
        return shorturl;
    }

    public void setShorturl(String shorturl) {
        this.shorturl = shorturl;
    }

    public String getShareurl() {
        return shareurl;
    }

    public void setShareurl(String shareurl) {
        this.shareurl = shareurl;
    }

    public String getWaveform() {
        return waveform;
    }

    public void setWaveform(String waveform) {
        this.waveform = waveform;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

I got this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga, PID: 24210
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class retrofit2.Response
        at com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.MusicListScreen$1.onResponse(MusicListScreen.java:86)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class retrofit2.Response
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:118)
        at com.minhhoang.yolo_yoga.MusicListScreen$1.onResponse(MusicListScreen.java:73)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 1):

MusicListScrenn class - Line 73:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

you need to access the body and not just "response" to do so use ".body()"
then you have another problem that YogaTracks isn't an Array, so you first need to deconstruct using first JSONObject...

Later you will find more problems because your response has two fields (headers, results) and your counting that you are already inside "results", so you need to also handle that for example creating a class "YogaTrackResponse" with those two fields "Header" and "Results" (List) and change in the API interface the Call to Call